# IUP split overflowing dialog?

Tags: c, split, overflow, expand, iup

The gui I'm trying to create follows this simple logic:

- IupDialog:

  - IupVbox

    - IupSplit

      - IupList
      - IupList

The lists are supposed to fill the split, and have scrollbars if needed. This is working, however, if I resize the window just a bit, the *IupVbox* becomes so big as to not fit the dialog and you can't see it's margins or the list's scrollbars. I'm probably doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
Ihandle *page, *box_options, *split, *btn_work, *dlg;
{
    list_entries = IupList(NULL);
    IupSetAttribute(list_entries, "EXPAND", "YES");
}
{
    list_log = IupList (NULL);
    IupSetAttribute(list_log, "EXPAND", "YES");
}

split = IupSplit(list_entries, list_log);
IupSetAttribute(split, "ORIENTATION", "VERTICAL");

page = IupVbox(split, NULL);
IupSetAttribute(page, "GAP", "20");
dlg = IupDialog(page);
IupShowXY (dlg, IUP_CENTER, IUP_CENTER);
```

Comment: Which native system? Windows or GTK? 
Which IUP version?
I run your code here in Windows and it is working with the latest IUP version.

Comment: I'm using the latest version, and I'm testing for mothe gtk and windows, can you fill one of the lists to see if it scrolls properly? To me, the problem happens even if the list is empty though...

Comment: Yes, it does scrolls properly. But if the dialog is too small it will crop the lists in the vertical. Why you don't post a screenshot?

Comment: I'm currently on linux, but on window's it's just the same. First image is the window as it opens, second image is when I resize horizontally just a little bit, third image is when I add many entries to the list, fourth image is when I resize the window just a little bit after those inserts. https://imgur.com/a/HKaHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs only when the list has many items, or an item is very large.

The problem is that the natural size of the list by default considers all its items. So it is larger than the actual size of the dialog, even when using expand=yes and inside the split. This is a historic behavior and cannot be changed.

To avoid that we have two attributes: VISIBLECOLUMNS and VISIBLELINES, that when set will disable this behavior of the natural size. For instance:

IupSetAttribute(list_entries, "VISIBLECOLUMNS", "10");
  IupSetAttribute(list_entries, "VISIBLELINES", "3");

Then your sample should work as you expected.

Comment: Does this mean I have to calculate how many lines would be visible, and recalculate every time the dialog is resized?

Comment: No, this means that you should use the VISIBLELINES to set a minimum number os lines that will be always visible, defining the crop size of the dialog contents. When the dialog is expanded further than that the actual number of lines in the list will be automatically expanded.